# Mobile opt in is not recording customers anywhere in exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, mobileconnect

I have set up a mobile opt in playbook with single opt in. Created two keywords "ADD" and "ADCDE" (more than four characters as mentioned in docs) and when I send SMS from my number to the short code I get a confirmation message that is set up in OptIn playbook but I can not find the number or contact details inside all contacts.

Am I doing anything wrong? Need to know how to get the details of those customers who are opting in via keywords and send out an email to our support group.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out?  I would like to know the answer to this.

Comment: unfortunately not yet, got response from support that this is limitied fuctionality as for now you can't track the subscribres separately..